Nested variable in regression model where factor has multiple levels
I have a situation where I have a factor variable $F$ and a continues variable say $X$. The factor variable takes on three levels, say ('x', 'y', 'z'), and $X$ is only defined if the value is $x$ or $y$. In particular, 'z' is coded as NA.
How can I model this situation in R? This answer suggest to do:
y ~ A + (A %in c('x', 'y')):X


Here I have to set the NA to some (e.g. -1), if all $X4 are positive - right since otherwise the model solving algorithm won't be able to handle this?
The formula specification does not seem to work? Now would I go about this?


Can you edit the post to tell us how this situation arises? With contextual information the probability of a useful answer will increase!
